# Using Variables in Curl Requests

Tags: curl

I'm really new to this and could use some beginner's help!

I'm trying to shorten a Curl command by using a variable for the token, but no matter how I try to format it with quotes or double quotes it just won't work.

The following CURL command works fine:

```
curl -X GET 'https://myurl.com/test' \
  -H 'auth-version: 2' \
  -H 'auth: 2_oXDMeAWeR3tiPLWjjPJHV_1OzeSwwW_0dyO0iLE67'
```

But when I try and use a variable for the auth value like this, it does not work:

```
token = "2_oXDMeAWeR3tiPLWjjPJHV_1OzeSwwW_0dyO0iLE67"
curl -X GET 'https://myurl.com/test' \
  -H 'auth-version: 2' \
  -H 'auth: "$token"'
```

I am also trying to do something similar using JSON but that fails as well:

```
token = "2_oXDMeAWeR3tiPLWjjPJHV_1OzeSwwW_0dyO0iLE67"
curl -X GET 'https://myurl.com/test' '{"auth-version": 2, "auth": "$token"}'
```

How can I get these both to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error specifically are you getting? I am pretty sure `token = ...` should fail with an error like `bash: token: command not found` because you are not allowed to have spaces between the name, =, and value. It should be `token=...`. Otherwise, depending on how you are running these curl commands you might need first export the token in order to access it in subsequent bash commands. i.e:

```
export token=2_oXDMeAWeR3tiPLWjjPJHV_1OzeSwwW_0dyO0iLE67
curl -X GET 'https://myurl.com/test' \
  -H 'auth-version: 2' \
  -H 'auth: "$token"'
```

You can check this by doing:

```
echo $token
 // if it prints nothing you need to use export
```

Comment: Your echo $token test works even when I use the original variable with spaces as shown above, i.e. token = "2_oXDMeAWeR3tiPLWjjPJHV_1OzeSwwW_0dyO0iLE67 so that's not the problem. I'm not getting a BASH error, but the host is not getting the variable value, so there's some problem with how i am formatting it, i 'm guessing. Any ideas? –

Comment: @macuseronline Are you just running these commands in the mac terminal?